# MySQL slave can't connect through SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, database-replication, slave

I have setup a MySQL server in AWS and another outside of AWS (hosted in China) that should replicate from each other.

This is currently working fine and both servers are running as they should.

Now I'm setting up another AWS and Chinese hosted server cluster but the Chinese slave for some reason can not connect to the AWS instance.

I setup an SSH tunnel like I did before which is running on port 3307.

If I log on to my Chinese hosted MySQL server and do:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u replicationuser -p
```

It connects to the AWS instance fine. However, when I set the replication up with the following:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO 
MASTER_HOST='127.0.0.1',
MASTER_USER='replicationuser ',
MASTER_PASSWORD='XXXXX',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
MASTER_LOG_POS=107,
MASTER_PORT=3307;
```

and then run `slave start;` it gives the following error:

```
2003 | error connecting to master 'replicationuser@127.0.0.1:3307'
```

does anybody have any clue why this doesnt work while my other setup is exactly the same and works fine.

I can connect through the SHH tunnel but my slave can not. The other way around works fine with the AWS instance connecting perfectly to the Chinese hosted MySQL server.

**EDIT**

my.cnf looks like this on server1:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
server-id=1
log-bin=mysql-bin
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=2

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

and on server2:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
server-id=2
log-bin=mysql-bin
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: Is this a separate cluster? So the second set of AWS and Chinese servers only talk between themselves and not to the first set? Are you using master-master replication here? What is the length of the passwords that the MySQL replication user is using?

Comment: yup, master-master replication and the working set is going to be my production servers and funny enoungh my test servers are not working, the lenght of the passwords are all the same on all of my servers

Comment: You might need to post all of your configs for both setups for someone to be able to help here. That will be your my.cnf files for all servers and show connectivity on each of them. I've also voted to move the question to dba.stackexchange.com where you might have better luck with the question.

Comment: thanks so far @ydaetskcoR, i posted both the my.cnf's both im pretty sure there is not that much exciting there..... super confused how my first set of servers is running fine and the other 1 is not while they both have the same setup

Comment: Can you connect with the mysql client over the tunnel? How are you establishing the tunnel?

Comment: yes i can connect to mysql client over the tunnel..... i made the tunnel just the same as i did on all the other servers like: ssh -f -i <path to key> <user@server>.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -N    and like i posted in my question i can connect over the tunnel by mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u replicationuser -p